# Filepath as a calculated filed/formula in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, path, concatenation

I want to create a column in my query (Google BigQuery) with the below mentioned filepath. I tried to use concat to split and combine the below but results in an error. Looking for an syntax that creates the below as a calculated field.

Below is a formula field from Alteryx workflow. Below is how the path is represented as a calculated field.

```
"\\system80025ust.localoffice.comp-any.com\FileShares\RegionDivisionServices\Nick\Process Case LOS " + DateTimeToday() + ".xlsx|||Data"
```

I tried the below

```
concat('system80025ust.localoffice.comp-any.com'+'\FileShares\RegionDivisionServices\Nick\Process Case LOS' + DateTimeToday() + '.xlsx|||Data') as File_name
```

```
Syntax Error: Illegal escape sequence: \F
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below

```
concat('system80025ust.localoffice.comp-any.com',r'\FileShares\RegionDivisionServices\Nick\Process Case LOS',current_date(),'.xlsx') as File_name
```

resulted in

[image]

few more variations:

```
'system80025ust.localoffice.comp-any.com'|| r'\FileShares\RegionDivisionServices\Nick\Process Case LOS' ||current_date() || '.xlsx'
```

Or

```
format('%s%s%s%s','system80025ust.localoffice.comp-any.com',r'\FileShares\RegionDivisionServices\Nick\Process Case LOS',string(current_date()),'.xlsx')
```

with same output

Comment: Hello Mikhail! Thank you for your response. Could you please include the sheet name as well?

Comment: show expected output, so I will try to add whatever is missing

Comment: \\system80025ust.localoffice.comp-any.com\FileShares\RegionDivisionServices\Nick\Process Case LOS\DateTimeToday() .xlsx|||Data

Comment: just add those extra to `'.xlsx'`! what the problem with this?